# Tampermonkey - save blob with GM_download?

Tags: javascript, blob, tampermonkey

I was wondering if there's a way to use Tampermonkey GM_download to save a blob to local filesystem without showing "save as"-window.

So you can automatically save a canvas image (instead of an url). I tried it like this:

```js
var blob = canvas.toDataURL({ format: 'png' });
arg = { 
  url: blob,
    name: "CustomFileName.png"
};
GM_download(arg);
```

But unfortunately that does not work. Does somebody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to add:

```
// @grant GM_download
```